# Sequence convergence with inequality

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, limits

**Find the limits:**

> $$lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^4 -n^3}{e^n}$$

***My Attempt:*** 
using L'Hospital's rule I got that the limit equals to $0$.

> **(1) the sequence $a_n$ given by**: 
>   $$a_n = \int_{1}^{t} e^{-nx} x^3 dx, \ n=1,2,\ldots $$

**then $a_n$ is the function value $F(n)$, as**:

$$F(t) = \int_{1}^{t} e^{-nx} x^3 dx$$

> **(2) use the mean value theorem on the function $F(t)$ in the interval $[1,n]$ to show that**: $$\frac{a_n}{n-1} = e^{-nc} c^3, \ c\in (1, n)$$

***My Attempt:*** 
I think I'm able to show this. Is it correct that $f(b)-f(a) = f(b) = a_n$ because $f(a) = o$ (integral from 1 to 1)?

> (3)  why is $$e^{-nc} c^3 (n-1) \le e^{-n} n^{3} (n-1), c\in (1,n) $$

***My Attempt:*** 
 Need help, I don't know how to approach this. What is the role of $c$ here?

> (4) Use the inequality to show that the sequence $a_n$ converges, and find the limit: $lim_{n\to \infty} a_n$

***My Attempt:***

(4) Not sure what to do here, maybe I have to solve (3) first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For (3), it's very simple:

- $c>1$ implies $-nc<-n$, and as the exponential is an increasing function, $\mathrm e^{-nc}<\mathrm e^{-n}$.
- the  $x^3$ function is also increasing, so $ c<n$ implies $c^3<n^3$

As these inequalities involve only positive numbers, we can multiply them to get
$$e^{-nc}c^3<e^{-n}n^3,$$
and there only remains to multiply both sides by the *positive* number $n-1$.

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking way to complicated as I usually do when I'm stuck. And since the right side of the inequality converges to 0 (task 1), then $lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = e^{-nc} c^3 (n-1)$ = left side of inequality must converge to 0 (task 4) as well since it is a positive smaller number?